# Deep linking is not working when app is not in background (app closed/killed)

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I have implemented this method so that when a user clicks the dynamic link it will be redirected to a specific page. Everything works alright while the app is running, but when I kill/close the app and try to do the same thing, it opens the app on the initial screen (Home Page). How can I make it work in this case?

```
Future<void> initDynamicLinks() async {
        FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink.listen((dynamicLinkData) {
          id = dynamicLinkData.link
              .toString()
              .substring(dynamicLinkData.link.toString().lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
          Get.to(
            () => Page(
              id: id,
            ),
          );
        }).onError((error) {
          if (kDebugMode) {
            print(error.message);
          }
        });
      }

void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    initDynamicLinks();
    super.initState();
}
```

Comment: all methods that helps in deep linking should be kept in the `main()` function of the app.

Answer (score 0):

I think `.onLink.listen()` function only get hit when app is resumed from background.
If you want your deeplink work when app have a fresh start then just put this code above `.onLink.listen()` function...

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await Firebase.initializeApp();
final PendingDynamicLinkData data = await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
final Uri deepLink = data?.link;
// Here you should navigate to your desired screen
```

Hope it helps you